# Basic Calculator "subtract" function is not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my first-ever program in python. I made a series of if statements for two numbers (num1 and num2). All of my code works for the add, multiply, and divide operators, but when I use the subtract operator, I either get no message, or it prints "Invalid Operator". I'm sure I've just done something simple wrong, as I just started learning python today, but I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
num1= float(input("enter first number:"))
operator = (input("enter operator:"))
num2= float(input("enter second number:"))
if operator== ("add" or "+" "sum"or "summation"):
    print(num1+num2)
elif operator== ("multiply" or "multiplication" or"*"):
    print(num1*num2)
elif operator== ("divide" or "division" or "/"):
    print(num1/num2)
elif operator== ("minus" or "subtract" or "-"):
    print(num1-num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Operator")
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\clubj\PycharmProjects\untitled9\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/clubj/PycharmProjects/untitled9/better calculator.py"
enter first number:32
enter operator:-
enter second number:6
Invalid Operator
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: please post your code here. Not the screen shot

Comment: Post the code instead of pictures , along with output and the expected output

Comment: So, what happens when the expressions in the parentheses are evaluated and **then** compared with `operator`?

Comment: So is it trying to evaluate and compare the input for the operator to all of what's inside the parentheses? ("minus" or "subtract" or "-")? The only thing that makes sense to me is to break up all of the (minus, subtract, and, -) into their own elif statements.

Comment: This doesn't work like you think `elif operator== ("minus" or "subtract" or "-")` Try: `elif operator in ("minus", "subtract", "-"):` to test if operator is one of these values.

Comment: this will work only if `(operator='minus) or (operator=='-')` better not to use or instead cerate tuples. by removing or element  `("minus", "subtract", "-")`

Comment: I tried using elif operator in ("minus" or "subtract" or "-"): , and ended up with the same result. Is the only way to do what I'm attempting is to break up the minus, subtract, and - into their own elif statements?

Comment: If you don't follow the @MarkMeyer comment then you have to write conditions like this `(operator== "add") or (operator=="+") or (operator=="sum") or (operator =="summation")`

Comment: Thanks a lot pygirl and @MarkMeyer . I haven't learned in statements yet, but I somewhat understand them right now, and I'm sure they'll make more sense when I get to them iny my course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced all the or and create a tuple instead.
your code will only if you write

```
if (operator== "add") or (operator=="+") or (operator=="sum") or (operator =="summation"):
```

Instead of

```
operator== ("add" or "+" or "sum" or "summation"):
```

---

```
num1= float(input("enter first number:"))
operator = (input("enter operator:"))
num2= float(input("enter second number:"))
print(operator)
if operator in ("add", "+", "sum", "summation"):
    print(num1+num2)
elif operator in ("multiply", "multiplication", "*"):
    print(num1*num2)
elif operator in ("divide", "division", "/"):
    print(num1/num2)
elif operator in ("minus", "subtract", "-"):
    print(num1-num2)
else:
    print("Invalid Operator")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `python builtin function eval()`. Eval function is mostly used in situations or applications which need to evaluate `mathematical` expressions. Also if the user wants to evaluate the `string` into `code` then can use eval function, because eval function evaluates the string expression and returns the integer as a result.

```
num1= input("enter first number:")
operator = input("enter operator:")
num2= input("enter second number:")
if operator in ["+", '-', '/', '*', '//', '%']:
    print(eval(num1+ operator+ num2))
else:
    print("Invalid operator")
```